# SQL Server : query join with multiple tables and Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I would like to join the following three SQL Server tables as shown. I know they have to be `JOIN`ed, but I think it is the `GROUP BY` that is throwing me off. I think it requires a `SELECT` within a `SELECT`?

```
select ActJobs.ID as JobID, ActJobs.JobName, ActJobs.CustomerID
From Job.ActiveJobsTbl as ActJobs

select Cus.ID as CustomerID, concat(Cus.LastName, ', ', Cus.FirstName) as Customer
From Customer.CustomerTbl as Cus

Select Est.ID_Job as JobID, Sum(Est.ItemAmount + Est.SalesTax) As Price
From Job.EstimateTbl as Est 
Group By Est.ID_Job
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great.  Have you tried using `JOIN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `JOIN` the first two tables, and turn the aggregated query to a subquery that you can also `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    ActJobs.ID as JobID, 
    ActJobs.JobName, 
    ActJobs.CustomerID,
    CONCAT(Cus.LastName, ', ', Cus.FirstName) as Customer,
    Est.Price
FROM 
    Job.ActiveJobsTbl AS ActJobs
    INNER JOIN Customer.CustomerTbl AS Cus ON Cus.ID = ActJobs.CustomerID
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ID_Job, SUM(ItemAmount + SalesTax) As Price 
        FROM Job.EstimateTbl
        GROUP BY ID_Job
    ) AS Est ON Est.ID_Job = ActJobs.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scalar subquery and join

```
select ActJobs.ID as JobID, ActJobs.JobName, ActJobs.CustomerID,
concat(Cus.LastName,', ',Cus.FirstName) as Customer,(select Sum(Est.ItemAmount + Est.SalesTax) from Job.EstimateTbl as Est where Est.ID_Job=ActJobs.ID) as price
From Job.ActiveJobsTbl as ActJobs
inner join Customer.CustomerTbl as Cus on Cus.ID as CustomerID=ActJobs.CustomerID
```